# Неправильно срабатывают условия, BAT/CMD/BATCH

Tags: cmd, bat

Есть такой скрипт:

```
@echo off

title delallch-02c1
cls
echo *=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*
echo *                                 *
echo *    Welcome to delallch-02c1!    *
echo *                                 *
echo *=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*
echo.
echo You need to use delallch=02c1? [Y/N] 
set /p Answer=

if /i "%Answer%"=="Y" ( call :Yeya ) else ( echo Incorrect answer )
if /i "%Answer%"=="N" ( call :Nope ) else ( echo Incorrect answer )
exit /b

:Yeya
echo lal
exit /b

:Nope
echo geg
exit /b
```

Но, почему-то, вывод такой:

[image: вывод]

Но по идее Incorrect answer не должен выводится.

Comment: Это ещё почему? Проверка первого условия. Истина. Прыжок на метку, вывод `lal`, возврат. Проверка второго условия. Ложно. Вывод `'Incorrect answer'`. Выход.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> if /i "%Answer%"=="Y" ( call :Yeya ) else ( echo Incorrect answer )
> if /i "%Answer%"=="N" ( call :Nope ) else ( echo Incorrect answer )
> ```

```
if /i "%Answer%"=="Y" ( call :Yeya ) else ( if /i "%Answer%"=="N" ( call :Nope ) else ( echo Incorrect answer ) )
```

Comment: И за что минус?

Comment: не я ставил минус, так что хз)

Comment: А разница goto и call?)))0
И вообще, есть какой-нибудь хороший источник знаний по .bat'никам на русском?

Comment: @ВасёкНедопограмисть, держи: https://rsdn.org/article/winshell/batanyca.xml

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> if /i "%Answer%"=="Y" ( call :Yeya ) else ( echo Incorrect answer )
> if /i "%Answer%"=="N" ( call :Nope ) else ( echo Incorrect answer )
> exit /b
> ```

Для скрипта в примере можно и вот так:

```
if /i "%Answer%"=="Y" ( goto :Yeya )
if /i "%Answer%"=="N" ( goto :Nope )
echo Incorrect answer
exit /b
```